# Deployed my smart contract using 'npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js' but it doesnt show me the contract address on the terminal

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I've been trying to deploy my solidity files, and this is what I get.
[image]

So basically, my files compile, and there is no error, but I do not get the deployed address, so they probably didn't deploy either.

I tried deleting the artifacts, cache and redeploying, but it gave the same result.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Edit: Here's my deploy.js

```
const { CRYPTODEVS_NFT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS } = require("../constants");
const hre = require("hardhat");


async function main() {
 // Deploy the FakeNFTMarketplace contract first
 const FakeNFTMarketplace = await ethers.getContractFactory(
  "FakeNFTMarketplace"
);
const fakeNftMarketplace = await FakeNFTMarketplace.deploy();
await fakeNftMarketplace.deployed();

console.log("FakeNFTMarketplace deployed to: ", await fakeNftMarketplace.address);

// Now deploy the CryptoDevsDAO contract
const CryptoDevsDAO = await ethers.getContractFactory("CryptoDevsDAO");
const cryptoDevsDAO = await CryptoDevsDAO.deploy(
  fakeNftMarketplace.address,
  CRYPTODEVS_NFT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
  {
    // This assumes your metamask account has at least 1 ETH in its account
    // Change this value as you want
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.01"),
  }
);
await cryptoDevsDAO.deployed();

console.log("CryptoDevsDAO deployed to: ", await cryptoDevsDAO.address);
}

// Async Sleep function
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

Edit: I added 'await' in the console.log and that worked but only one of my solidity files deployed. For the second i get this:
[image]

All solutions to this were to get if my filename and contract name were similar and I already checked, its the same.

Comment: Post your deploy.js

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue.  Unlike Truffle or Brownie deployments, in Hardhat you need to console log the address. (Your contracts DID deploy, you just haven't been shown where)

Example:

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {

    // Getting a contract to deploy
    var newContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("newContract");

    // Deploying a new contract
    var deployedContract = await newContract.deploy();
    console.log("Contract address is: " + await deployedContract.address);
}

main();
```